# hide div based on textfield input with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need to hide a div(class "card") until the user enters text into the textfield. 
I'm using angularJS for my app. I guess i have to use `ng-show`but how can I get this to work? I appreciate your help.

This is my code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchBox" class="search1" placeholder="Suchen...">

    <div ng-repeat="item in posts | filter:searchBox" class="card">
      <h3 class="w">{{item.storeName}}</h3>
     [...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply set ng-show equal to the model value. When it's empty ng-show will evaluate to false and hide the div. When the input has a value ng-show will evaluate to true and show the div.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in posts | filter:searchBox" class="card" ng-show="searchBox">
```

Answer (score 1):

add ng-show or ng-if to the element you want to show after value is entered

```
<div ng-repeat="item in posts | filter:searchBox" class="card" ng-if="searchBox">
```

or you can wrap this div with another div

```
  <div ng-if="searchBox">
    <div ng-repeat="item in posts | filter:searchBox" class="card">
```

**but** you do not have to do this... given that the filter will give results only if there is any value matching as per the `searchBox`, hence if there are not values, ng-repeat will not create any element

Comment: btw you should also read about the differences in `ng-if` and `ng-show`. if i have to make a choice, i do generally prefer to use `ng-if` over `ng-show/ng-hide`